# PHP PDO MySQL Insert error, but works as direct query on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im using PHP PDO to let my Android app talk to a MySQL database.

Here's my PHP file:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=x;dbname=x", "x", "x");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "INSERT INTO k_user_groep(group, user, rol) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($_GET['groupid'], $_GET['user'], $_GET['rol']));
?>
```

The table is designed as follows:
groupid references a unique index in other table,
user references a primary key in other table,
rol references nothing.

Directly in MySQL the following query works:

```
INSERT INTO `k_user_groep`(`group`, `user`, `rol`) VALUES ('1', 'test', 'v');
```

This is my call on the PHP file:

```
x.php?groupid=1&user=test&rol=v
```

It returns the following:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group, user, rol) VALUES ('1', 'test', 'v')' at line 1' in x.php:7 Stack trace: #0 x.php(7): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in x.php on line 7
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`group` [is a reserved word in mySQL.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

It works in your second example because you're wrapping the column name in backticks.

Answer (score 0):

Well it clearly is not the same query you're trying in your PDO code and in the MySQL client — you have all your identifiers quoted in the client, while none are quoted in the PDO code.